# Errors while attempting to install a Big Sur VM with Parallels 18 on Monterey 12.6

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, parallels-desktop

Looked at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/394870), but it seemed to be assuming Intel. All the other questions involved installing newer macOS than the Host. I couldn't find an Apple Silicon (M1) question installing older VMs.

**Note:** I'm current running a Monterey VM just fine. I just need one running Big Sur.

I used this command to create the VM:

```
/Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_macvm_create ~/Downloads/UniversalMac_11.6_20G165_Restore.ipsw ~/Parallels/macOS\ Big\ Sur.macvm --disksize 40000000000
```

When I start this VM I get this error:
Cannot retrieve the hardware model data.
[image: error]

The `.ipsw` was downloaded [from here](https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2021FallFCS/fullrestores/071-97388/C361BF5E-0E01-47E5-8D30-5990BC3C9E29/UniversalMac_11.6_20G165_Restore.ipsw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Parallels Knowledge Base](https://kb.parallels.com/125561) entry that clarified the way Apple Silicon (M1) VMs work in Parallels. From the link, I have my answer. Unfortunately, it can apparently not be done.

### Limitations

> To run a macOS Monterey VM on Mac computers with Apple M series chips, Parallels Desktop 17 uses new technology introduced in macOS Monterey, that's why it is not possible to run earlier versions of macOS on a Mac with Apple M series chips.

The implication of this limitation is that you may not run Big Sur virtual machines at all on Apple Silicon.